# Protocol extension method dispatch in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, polymorphism, xcode7

I'm facing a problem regarding protocols methods dispatch.

I have a class hierarchy that looks like that:

```
protocol E {
    func test()
}

extension E {
    func test() {
        print("jello")
    }
}

class A: E {

}

class B: A {
    func test() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```

But when I call `test` on an instance of class `B` statically forced to be typed `A`, "jello" gets printed, not "hello".

```
let b: A = B()  // prints "jello" not "hello"
b.test()
```

My understanding is that `test` method printing "jello" gets "integrated" into instances of `A` (since `A` conforms to `E` protocol). I'm then providing another implementation of `test` inside `B` (that inherits form `A`). I thought polymorphism would work here and calling `test` on `B` instance that are stored inside `A` references would print `hello`. What's happening here?

It's perfectly working when not using any protocol:

```
class A {
    func test() {
        print("jello")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func test() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

let b: A = B() // prints "hello"
b.test()
```

What's different from adopting a protocol that adds new methods to my parent class and providing a new implementation in a subclass, than having directly written this method in the parent class and then overriding it in a subclass?

Do you guys have any workaround?

Comment: Not the precise behavior you are seeing, but closely related: http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smells like a bug.

The only workaround I came up with was very ugly...

```
protocol E {
    func test()
}

func E_test(_s: E) {
    print("jello")
}

extension E {
    func test() { E_test(self) }
}

class A: E {
    func test() { E_test(self) }
}

class B: A {
    override func test() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

let b: A = B()
b.test()
```

Comment: This a indeed a solution, but very ugly :) Will file a radar just to make sure.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's intended behavior. Nonetheless, I'm fighting with this issue too right now :)

Comment: @manmal If Apple intended this, yet all the programmers find it counterintuitive and end up hacking around it, then I think it can be classified as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug indeed. Here is the link to it: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-103